# Notepad++ replace between .dodo? to </dada>

Tags: regex

hey guys my regex skills suck and was looking for some help.  I am using Notepad++ and am looking to easily replace everything between the following

example:

```
.dodo?ReplaceMe</dada>
```

Its in many lines i need to replace often so rather than hunting hightlighting and replacing i was hoping to score an easyier regex method that will save me time. The replace can include question mark if it makes it easier.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can match your pattern using `\.dodo\?([^<]*)<\/dada>`.

- `\.dodo\?` matches `.dodo?` - you need to escape the `.` and `?`?
- `([^<]*)` matches all characters **aren't** a `<`, `ReplaceMe` in this case, in a matching group
- `<\/dada>` matches `</dada>` - you need to escape the `/`

View it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/bM2wE6/1

Answer (score 0):

Use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=\.dodo\?).*?(?=<\/dada>)
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/dG2dH8/1)

Comment: That worked mint first shot Thanks so much I really appreciate it u have saved me so much time.

Comment: @BobbyPeters, happy to help.